# Can one apply for a Schengen visa while visiting the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, pakistani-citizens

My mother is a Pakistani national and 63 years old. She has a valid 5-year multiple UK visit visa. She is travelling to the UK in December and will stay for 3 months in the UK.

I am a British citizen and we want to go to Switzerland and Italy over New Year's.

Can she apply for a Schengen visa during her stay in UK? If not, how early can she apply from Pakistan.

Comment: If your mother is dependent on you then you should apply for a free visa under the freedom of movement directive.  You may be able to do that at the consulate in the UK, but it will definitely be more likely for them to accept the application in Pakistan than in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

No, she has to apply from Pakistan.

> Visa applications for UK residents are to be submitted at the Swiss
>   Visa Application Centres in London, Manchester, Cardiff or Edinburgh
>   (UK).

You mom is not a UK resident but rather a visitor. Therefore she has to apply from Pakistan where is a resident.

There are very rare exceptions when applications are entertained from outside your home domicile - but these generally have to do with emergencies.

You can apply as early as 90 days before your travel date.

To apply from Pakistan she has to apply via VFS/Gerry's which have offices in Islamabad, Karachi and Lahore (no appointment required); or she can apply directly via the embassy but you have to schedule an appointment in advance, and these are limited.

Documents required:

- Photographs
- Biometric data (fingerprints and photos) collected in person at VFS or the embassy.
- Visa application
- Fees (including service fees if applied via VFS)
- Passport (valid for 6 months after travel date)
- Proof of funds (bank statements, etc.)
- Travel itinerary (travel can be Pakistan - London - Switzerland, it doesn't have to be direct to Switzerland)
- Evidence of home ties
- Hotel accommodations in Switzerland

For your mom as she has a long term visa for the UK, I believe her application will have a smoother process of getting approved.

Comment: If the mother is dependent then she can apply for free under EU freedom of movement rules.